# eth_call out of gas

Tags: solidity

```
    function univ2Pairs(address[] memory factory,uint256[] memory pair)public view returns
    (
        bool[]  memory c,
        bytes[] memory d,
        bytes[] memory token0,
        bytes[] memory token1,
        bytes[] memory getReserves
    )
    {
        uint256 i =0;
        c                               = new bool[](uint256(factory.length));
        d                               = new bytes[](uint256(factory.length));
        token0                          = new bytes[](uint256(factory.length));
        token1                          = new bytes[](uint256(factory.length));
        getReserves                     = new bytes[](uint256(factory.length));

        for(i;i<factory.length;i++)
        {
            (c[i],d[i])                 = address(factory[i]).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("allPairs(uint256)",pair[i]));
            if(c[i])
            {
                (address pairAddress)   = abi.decode(d[i],(address));
                (,token0[i])            = address(pairAddress).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("token0()"));
                (,token1[i])            = address(pairAddress).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("token1()"));
                (,getReserves[i])       = address(pairAddress).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSignature("getReserves()"));
            }
        }
    }
```

then run

```
address[]=["0xb0b670fc1f7724119963018db0bfa86adb22d941","0xb0b670fc1f7724119963018db0bfa86adb22d941","0xb0b670fc1f7724119963018db0bfa86adb22d941"]
pair[]=["999999","99999","1"]
```

```
return result is    out of gas  .. why I don't understand.
```

Comment: Probably because its going in infinite loop or there's some wrong state update, Please crosscheck everything and try again.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: How are you making the eth_call? which network are you using?

Comment: rinkeby test...

Comment: $a          =  [
              '0'  =>
              [
               'from'     =>     '0x4b4b7ea9c95c247214f2072b189afd87d9c355cb',
               'data'     =>     $a,
               'to'     =>     $b,
              ],
              '1'   => 'latest'
             ];

Comment: I want to query uni pairs。。。